# How to place a non-sticky button inside a scrollview to the bottom of a main view in Swiftui? Spacer seems to have no effect inside a scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to place a button inside a scrollview to the bottom of the main view with some bottom padding after a spacer. But looks like there is no effect of spacer inside a scrollview. I don't want to hardcode spacer with minWidth. Any suggestion would be appreciated?

```
 ScrollView {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hi")) {
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Submit")
                        .frame(height: 42)
                }
                .buttonStyle(FilledButton())
                .frame(width: 248, height: 42, alignment: .center)
            }
            .padding(.top, 33)
            .padding(.bottom, 12)
        }
    }
```

Comment: ScrollView does not have own size, so *inside a scrollview to the bottom of the main view* is senseless. Maybe you meant *over* (or above) ScrollView. Why do you need scrollview in this case at all?

Comment: The problem comes when content is in small device like iPhone 8. So I used scrollview but for big device I don't need scrollview and spacer works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a Geometry Reader to grab the height of the ScrollView itself.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hi")) {
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Text("Submit")
                                .frame(height: 42)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(FilledButton())
                        .frame(width: 248, height: 42, alignment: .center)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 33)
                    .padding(.bottom, 12)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```